# Adding Paypal "Buy Now" button to the html file

Tags: meteor, paypal

am following [Paypal tutorial](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/buynow_buttons/) for adding "Buy now" button. I pasted the button code as it is shown in the code below

```
<template name="itemDetails">
        <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p class="lead">Categories</p>
                <div class="list-group">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Android</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">IOS</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Unity</a>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block sell">Post</button>

                 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="someRandomeValue">
                <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
                <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
            </form>


            </div>
```

but i can't see the button when navigate to the page! why?

Comment: what happens when you remove the `.sell` class?

Comment: @timgavin still nothing happens, the button doesn't appear

Comment: The code is correct, so you must have an issue elsewhere - probably in your CSS. Start removing classes from the HTML until you're just down to the bare Bootstrap classes and see if it appears.

Comment: @timgavin i just tried to open in in safari browser. i could see the i clickable sentence that says "PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" but without the image of the button, i was testing it before with chrome. the is confusing!

Comment: The code you're using is for a Bootstrap button, NOT the PayPal button, which is why you're not seeing the PayPal button. You need to go into your PayPal account and get the button code that it generates for that particular button.

Comment: @timgavin no, i copy pasted the exact same code i got from Paypal. didn't change anything from it.

Comment: You're not showing that in your example.

Comment: @timgavin is it safe? i was afraid it might have some info that i shouldn't share. is it safe to share?

Comment: That's up to you to decide. Take out any information you feel is unsafe.

Comment: @timgavin i edited my question including the form

Comment: That code is fine; it works for me. Your problem is most likely elsewhere.

Comment: @timgavin okay, will try to figure it out, thanks :)

Comment: @timgavin i solved it, it turned to be silly mistake, i will post the answer

Answer (score 1):

It turned to be silly mistake which i didn't notice earlier.
i had to include this line of code in the server side

```
BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll( '*.paypalobjects.com' );
```